# admin filters in Grappelli

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a simple model that displays product pages by client:

```
class PostPage(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='POST')
    ...
```

and in the admin, I'd like to be able to sort the records by client, thus my admin.py has got:

```
class PostPageAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('client',)
```

this provides the admin changelist filter I'm looking for in Django's built-in admin however, when I switch to grappelli, the filter list disappears (and the delete button next to the actions dropdown disappears also, though this may be a separate issue). Does this sound like an incorrect grappelli implementation or does grappelli perhaps require different filter code in the admin.py than the default admin install?

Answer (score 0):

Grapelli has it's own configuration that you have to enter separately...
AFAIK auto-generated dashboards are not always right.
You have to create your own and configure it with filter and button and so on...
[grapelli docs](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_api.html)

Comment: thanks. i did look at the grappelli docs but I didn't see a whole lot devoted to changelists and changelist filters.